# How to complete the permutation algorithm in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm

For example, "abc" is a string, and its arrangement is as follows
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba 
If there are duplicate elements in the string, deduplication is also considered.
For example, a string like "aba" is arranged as follows 
aab
aba
baa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate all permutation of a set in O(n), this impossible since there exist O(n!) permutations, so just iterating over them is impossible in O(n). 
However if you just want to check if "acb" could is a permutation of "abc" this is possible for example by counting the occurrences of each letter in both words.

Comment: What you are talking about is the normal situation. I would like to ask if there are other ideas to achieve this standard.

Comment: What do you mean with this standard? What do you want to do? Do you want to list all permutations or do you want to check if list A is a permutation of list B?

Comment: List all the cases really O(n!), I understand the wrong, what efficient algorithms can be listed